# How to set same selector for all elements?

Tags: android, user-interface, checkbox, css-selectors

I need to have custom checkboxes which wasn't that tricky. I made checkbox_selector to drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_disabled" /><!-- disabled -->
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked_focused" /><!-- pressing unchecked box -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked_focused" /><!-- pressing checked box -->
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_checked" /><!-- checked box -->
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkbox_unchecked" /><!-- unchecked box -->

</selector>
```

But the problem is that every checkbutton I make, I've to add

```
<Checkbox
   android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector" />
```

Trying to google answer for a some time and maybe I just can't find the right words.

Can I say somewhere that every checkbox in this application should use this @drawable/checkbox_selector?

**EDITED:**
Saying in styles.xml

```
<style name="customCheckBox">
   <item android:button>@drawable/checkbox_selector</item>
</style>
```

Worked for me in Android 2.3.3
But when I tried with Android 4.0.3 it doesn't work. Any Idea why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use style for this purpose:
Just set in your style.xml this:

```
 <style name="CustomCheckBox" >
    <item name="android:button">"@drawable/checkbox_selector</item>
 </style>
```

And then just apply your theme to all your Checkbox, doing this:

```
 <Checkbox style="@style/CustomCheckBox" />
```

For more reference about styles just read:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: he will call the stile for every checkbox, same issue or even bad

Comment: Nope, because I can say in the theme file <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/customCheckBox</item>

Comment: You can also set the style in the your custom checkbox constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you may define your them in manifest for all control (theme contains your style)

```
android:theme="@style/CustomCheckBox"
```